# Can NodeJS use a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, web

I have a MySQL database, and I would like use a NodeJS framework like Express or Meteor for my backend site. But, when I look for this, they mostly use MongoDB.

Do you have any idea about that, or other framework to connect a MySQL database?

Comment: Yes, of course it can.

Comment: ``npm install mysql``, and then use it normally through a ``require``

Comment: But, there is no conflict with MongoDB ?

Comment: What do you mean *"conflict"*? You could use both with the same app if you wanted to (see "polyglot persistence").

Comment: I would like to store "temporary" data into mongoDB and other in MySQL database on the server side. Thank you for your response !

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use MySQL database. For that, you can Sequelize or knex as your ORM.
Please see more info about these packages in npm website searching them.